# launcher problem 1.3.7 windows 7 64-bit at starting

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image: 26 failures )]

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit Home Basic.  How can I fix this?

Comment: What is this? A crash report for ants?

Comment: `Connection Timed Out`
Check your firewall settings.

Comment: i tried and close it ..didn't work

Comment: Please take a look here:
http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/2199385-minecraft-launcher-137-unabale-to-play-previous-versions-of-minecraft/

Comment: I think this is Different problem...it looks like blocking (ad) he there is file to try downlaoding it to know what it blocking

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to copy and paste the contents of the log? Perhaps you should try that in the future.

Comment: I'll vote to close it because it's difficult to read. Please edit your question and add the log as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Connection Timed Out` error means that something is blocking you from accessing Minecraft.net

Make sure that you have disabled any firewalls that you may have installed and that you are on an unrestricted internet connection.

Comment: gonna try...
man...i really don't know why but it's work..i think i should restart my lap and then close firewall before start minecraft or restart again! ...thanks to all<--